# Using a for loop to separate nested lists into its own variable

Tags: python, list

I am trying to iterate and separate nested lists.
My data input is currently something like this. .

```
mainlist = [['1', 'HiII', '0', '1407', '0', 'Commander', '11.06.2018'], 
            ['2', 'wEEDzy', '0', '1184', '0', 'Private', '24.03.2021']]
```

My goal is to use a `for` loop to separate each list into its own list, then pull specific variables from that list, then output it to a text file. I want to pull only values 1, 3, & 5 from each list.

Now that you know my objective, I am trying to use a `for` loop to separate each list into its own variable and make that list only those 3 values that are needed.

This is the desired output (each assigned to a variable, then added to a .txt value)

```
['HiII', '1407', 'Commander']
['wEEDzy','1184', 'Private']
```

My current code is this: , which separates a list and then adds only the things I want from the list to it.

```
member1 = list(mainlist[0])
templist = []
templist.append(member1[1])
templist.append(member1[3])
templist.append(member1[5])
```

What I can't figure out is how to do this for each one for x amount of members so I don't copy and paste it everytime. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are specifically taking `mainlist[0]`. Just do `for member in mainlist` and then replace `member1` with the loop's variable `member`... Or just do it in a list-comprehension: `new_list = [member[1::2] for member in mainlist]`

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```py
for member in mainlist:
    templist = [member[1], member[3], member[5]]
    # do something with templist
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to separate variables is usually a bad idea: you have to figure out how to generate and maintain those separate variables.  This is why programming languages have lists, dicts, and other data structures.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables).

Instead, simply extract the data you need into a new list, and iterate through that:

```
templist = [[member[pos] for pos in (1, 3, 5)] for member in mainlist]
```

This gives you a similar nested list, with only the desired data.

Now you open your file, iterate through `templist`, and write the data in your desired format.  I trust that you can finish from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice notation (find a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/5239030) within a list comprehension, as already shown by other answers.

Slicing this case: **start** from index 1 up to the end (**stop**) in **step** of two: `[1::2]`.

So, for your list:

```
mainlist = [['1', 'HiII', '0', '1407', '0', 'Commander', '11.06.2018'], 
            ['2', 'wEEDzy', '0', '1184', '0', 'Private', '24.03.2021']]
```

Go this way:

```
tmp = [sublist[1::2] for sublist in mainlist]
#=> [['HiII', '1407', 'Commander'], ['wEEDzy', '1184', 'Private']]
```

Now that `tmp` contains the filtered sublists, use it for your purpose.